# Can a Silence Hallow be resisted?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, hearing

[Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) allows me to bind a powerful effect to an area, such as Silence.

> Silence. No sound can emanate from within the area, and no sound can reach into it.

However, effects on the area which affect creatures can be resisted with a successful save.

> Some of these effects apply to creatures in the area; you can designate whether the effect applies to all creatures, creatures that follow a specific deity or leader, or creatures of a specific sort, such as orcs or trolls. When a creature that would be affected enters the spell's area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there, it can make a Charisma saving throw. On a success, the creature ignores the extra effect until it leaves the area.

Now, presumably this doesn't apply to an effect like Darkness. It doesn't affect a creature, it just creates darkness which affects a creature. Besides, the darkness is real - what would a successful save do? Let you see through the darkness like an illusion?

> Darkness. Darkness fills the area. Normal light, as well as magical light created by spells of a lower level than the slot you used to cast this spell, can't illuminate the area.

But what about Silence? It looks like it just prevents sound itself, instead of actually affecting creatures. A spell that teleported an arrow away from its target wouldn't affect the archer - all this does is prevent sound from coming out. Besides, the spell Silence doesn't allow a save - why should this?

Comment: silence is just darkness but with sound instead of light

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Silence affects an area.

It's written in the description:

> **Silence.** No sound can emanate from within the *area*, and no sound can reach into it.

Creatures are not mentioned here. This effect obviously targets an area, not a creature. The effects that apply to creatures all have the phrase "affected creatures" in the description:

> **Courage.** *Affected creatures* can't be frightened while in the area.
>
> **Energy Protection.** *Affected creatures* in the area have resistance to one damage type of your choice, except for bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing.
>
> **Energy Vulnerability.** *Affected creatures* in the area have vulnerability to one damage type of your choice, except for bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing.
>
> **Extradimensional Interference.** *Affected creatures* can't move or travel using teleportation or by extradimensional or interplanar means.
>
> **Fear.** *Affected creatures* are frightened while in the area.
>
> **Tongues.** *Affected creatures* can communicate with any other creature in the area, even if they don't share a common language.

Except for Everlasting Rest, which affects dead bodies who cannot make saving throws.

Note, making a saving throw to resist one of these affects *is* optional:

> When a creature that would be affected enters the spell's area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there, it *can* make a Charisma saving throw. On a success, the creature ignores the extra effect until it leaves the area.

Comment: Very good point! Now I'm imagining someone trying to resist the Courage aura.